# Is it possible to create "customeraddress" entity record using "/api/data/<version>/' API?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I tried to create "customeraddress" record but got such an error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "0x80040205",
    "message": "Parent id not set for address type 1071",
    "innererror": {
        "message": "Parent id not set for address type 1071",
        "type": "System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]",
        "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.CreateInternal(Entity entity, InvocationContext invocationContext, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, Dictionary`2 optionalParameters)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataExecutionContext.CreateOrganizationResponse(Entity entity)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataServiceDataProvider.CreateEdmEntity(CrmODataExecutionContext context, String edmEntityName, EdmEntityObject entityObject, Boolean isUpsert)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.PostEntitySetImplementation(String& entitySetName, EdmEntityObject entityObject)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone provide me with a solution to this problem?

Comment: I also tried to write proper "parentid" (in my case it was "account" record id) but got another one error: 
"code": "0x0",
        "message": "An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: Does not support untyped value in non-open type.\r\n   at ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to create a new `customeraddress` using below snippet & payload. I recommend you to [use CRM REST Builder](https://www.wipfli.com/insights/articles/tc-crm-rest-builder-dynamics-crms-web-api)

```
var entity = {};
entity.name = "Arun test";
entity.line1 = "100 Test ave";
entity["parentid_account@odata.bind"] = "/accounts(A6271E63-62B8-E911-A839-000D3A315A07)";

Xrm.WebApi.online.createRecord("customeraddress", entity).then(
    function success(result) {
        var newEntityId = result.id;
        alert(newEntityId);
    },
    function(error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    }
);
```

Alternate version with `XMLHttpRequest` along with `/api/data/v9.1/customeraddresses` endpoint:

```
var entity = {};
entity.name = "Arun test";
entity.line1 = "100 Test ave";
entity["parentid_account@odata.bind"] = "/accounts(A6271E63-62B8-E911-A839-000D3A315A07)";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/customeraddresses", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            var uri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
            var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
            var matches = regExp.exec(uri);
            var newEntityId = matches[1];
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

Comment: as far as I understand there is no possibility to create "customeraddress" entity record without providing parentid. Am I right?